# PhpStorm - move refactoring does not work for file paths

Tags: php, refactoring, phpstorm

I have the following folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Previously, the classes were placed directly in /rest/ folder and they were referenced so in autoload.php:

[image]

After doing Refactor->Move for all classes in PhpStorm to /rest/class/ directory, PhpStorm does not refactor string file paths (seen on the above screenshot). Does someone know why is that? Standard filename refactor works fine. Is there better way to change folder structure for the project without the need to check all the references in other files?

Comment: I have the same issue. There is a [discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207223975-File-move-refactoring-not-working) on their support website.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been reported some time ago as https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-33398 but did not have much votes there. Would be great if you could vote for it with Thumb Up button and leave a comment to get a devs attention.